# Month year expiration drop down in Stripe form angularjs

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe with my angularJs app. Although the code below works fine, I wanted a month, year drop down for the expiry date.

```
    <form stripe-form="stripeCallback" name="checkoutForm">
        <input ng-model="number" placeholder="Card Number"
             payments-format="card" payments-validate="card" name="card"/><br>
        <input ng-model="expiry" placeholder="Expiration"
             payments-format="expiry" payments-validate="expiry"
             name="expiry"/><br>
        <input ng-model="cvc" placeholder="CVC" payments-format="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" name="cvc"/><br>
        <button class="checkout" type="submit" ng-disabled="checkoutForm.card.$invalid">Checkout</button>
    </form>
```

How do I integrate two drop downs with this form?

Thanks.

Comment: This link https://www.airpair.com/javascript/integrating-stripe-into-angular-app would be helpful..

Comment: I have read this blog, there isn't any mention about separate month, year inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines would probably give you what you need.

```
<select ng-model='expiry_month' ng-change='expiry=expiry_month+"/"+expiry_year'>...</select>
<select ng-model='expiry_year' ng-change='expiry=expiry_month+"/"+expiry_year'>...</select>
```